# How to get a layer with python in gimp?

Tags: python, gimp

I want to get a specific layer in gimp with python.

I have the image with two layers.
I found the command the `num_layers, layer_ids = pdb.gimp_image_get_layers(image)`

when I run the command I get the output

```
num_layers = 2
layer_ids  = (5, 4)
```

I found the commands `layer = pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_name(image, name)` and `layer = pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_tattoo(image, tattoo)`.

How do I get a specific layer?

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to determine on which layer your script/plugin should work, the plugin registration should declare parameters that start with with a PF_IMAGE and a PF_DRAWABLE. These will be set to the image and active layer when the script is called.
- You can also retrieve the active layer using `image.active_layer` but this is dangerous, your plugin could have been called on a mask or channel, using the previous method is normally the way to do it. This method has its uses when trying things in the Python-fu console.
- If you created the layer in your script, the layer has been returned by the API call, so keep it in a variable to reuse it later.
- For a specific layer, it will depend on the criteria, you can

  - filter by name: `[l from image.layers if l.name='XXX'][0]`,
  - filter on position in the stack:

    - `image.layers[0]` for the top,
    - `image.layers[-1]` for the "Background" at the bottom.
  - You can also find the first visible or linked.

  But doing so is usually a bad idea.
- If you want to retrieve a layer from a previous processing, you can "tattoo" it (`pdb.gimp_item_set_tattoo(item, tattoo)` where `tattoo` is an integer that you pick as your signature), and then retrieve it in a subsequent processing using `pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_tattoo(image, tattoo)`). The tattoo will be saved as part of the image and so will survive beyond a work session.